# C++20: boost::algorithm::to_lower( std::u8string )

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, c++20, stdstring

This C++20 program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::u8string s8 = u8"ABC";
    boost::algorithm::to_lower( s8 );
    std::cout << std::string( s8.begin(), s8.end() );
}
```

1. Works fine in Visual Studio 2019 (prints "abc")
2. Throws std::bad_cast in gcc 11
3. Fails to compile in clang

What is the expected result here?

Comment: This seems to [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/bW3KchzGP) with Clang as well, and it throws `std::bad_cast`, same as GCC. What  compiler error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I tried https://wandbox.org/ and got ```error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::ctype<char8_t>'```

Comment: Could you share a link to the actual demo you're running?

Comment: @Fedor: "*`boost::algorithm::to_lower( s8 );`*" If you want legitimate Unicode-aware lowercasing code, that's not going to do it. And if you don't want that, I'm not sure why you need a UTF-8 string here.

Comment: @cigien, here is the link: https://wandbox.org/permlink/D6AgCK2IXbPE4csk

Comment: @NicolBolas, for me it would be fine if it worked at least for ASCII characters. But I was surprised by std::bad_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-based strings don't work with locale-aware constructs like pretty much all of [Boost.Algorithm's text conversion stuff](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html). And even if they did work, they would be unable to perform *Unicode*-based case conversion.

You need a library that is both Unicode-aware and knowledgeable about `char8_t`.

Comment: But why the same program behaves differently in Visual Studio and gcc?

Comment: The link provided does not say anything about UTF. So this answer looks like a personal opinion.

Comment: @TioTeo: "*The link provided does not say anything about UTF.*" Right. The OP is asking about doing Unicode-based conversions. And the text at the link does not talk about Unicode conversions; it talks about locale-based conversions. Therefore, it won't work for what the OP wants.